# Is $\mathbb{Z}$ contained in $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was wondering if $\mathbb{Z}$ is contained in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, the group of integers modulo $p$?
As I can take every integer and send it to it equivalence class I believe that I could be possible?

Comment: Well $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is finite...

Comment: Here it is necessary to define what "contained" means. Certainly there is no monomorphism from the integers to $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Answer (score 7):

You can see that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is finite and $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite, so it cannot be "contained" in it.

There is a canonical function $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}_p$, that sends a number $n$ to its residue modulo $p$, but it is not injective (though it is surjective).

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is brutally, massively overloaded, so I recommend denoting the integers modulo $p$ by writing: $$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}.$$

It's up to you, of course.

To answer your question: kind of.

Recall that there's a ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ given by $k \mapsto k+p\mathbb{Z}$.

We can view this as an "inclusion" $$\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$$

if we want. For instance, anytime we denote $3+5\mathbb{Z}$ simply as "$3$", we're implicitly regarding the aforemention homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ as an inclusion.

But since this "inclusion" isn't injective, some care has to be taken. For instance, just because $3=8$ in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, doesn't mean $3=8$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Many mathematicians would feel uncomfortable calling this an "inclusion" for precisely this reason.

(I'm not one of them.)